# merge two ini files by their block name

Tags: awk, ini

How to merge two blocks of two ini file ?

Hi, I have two ini files which stores data in blocks as below:

```
 -->cat f1
[default]
a1=1
b1=2
c1=3

[foo]
d=1
e1=5


 -->cat f2
[default]
a2=5
b2=6

[foo]
c2=7
d2=8
e2=9

[bar]
f2=10
```

I need to merge these two files as follow:

```
[default]
a1=1
b1=2
c1=3
a2=5
b2=6

[foo]
d=1
e1=5
c2=7
d2=8
e2=9


[bar]
f2=10
```

I honestly do not know from were to start and what logic is needed or the tool.

some of the foolish things I tried to get the directions are:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0;next} $0 in a{print}' f1 f2
[default]

[foo]

awk -vRS='' '{$1=$1}1' f1 f2 |awk '!a[$1]++'
[default] a1=1 b1=2 c1=3
[foo] d=1 e1=5
[bar] f2=10
```

Comment: What if the files contain the same key but with different values? What about the commented lines (if any).

Comment: `f2` should overwrite the key of `f1` in case of dups.  Duplicate comments are ok, I can live with that.

Comment: You will not say that the day a comment will try to stab you while you sleep.

Comment: but my requirement looks so challenging cannot think of comments at least for now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '/^$/{
   next
}
/^\[.*\]$/{
   hdr = $0
   next
}
a[hdr] != "" {
   a[hdr] = a[hdr] ORS $0
   next
}
{
   a[hdr] = $0
   seq[++n] = hdr
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      print seq[i] ORS a[seq[i]] (i<n ? ORS : "")
}' f1 f2
```

```
[default]
a1=1
b1=2
c1=3
a2=5
b2=6

[foo]
d=1
e1=5
c2=7
d2=8
e2=9

[bar]
f2=10
```

**Details:**

- `/^$/` matches all empty lines that we simply ignore
- `/^\[.*\]$/` matched header names that we store in `hdr` variable
- `a[hdr] != "" { ... }` when we already processed `hdr` once then we append a new line and current line in array `a` indexed by `hdr`
- Else we just store current line in array `a` indexed by `hdr`. Also we store `hdr` in another array `seq` indexed by incrementing number to print data in order
- In the `END` block we loop through `seq` array and print each header and details block. We append a newline if we have more data to process.

Comment: thanks , can you please explain in high level so  I can follow

Comment: Sure, I am going to add more details in answer.

Comment: `ord` is the name of a function in some awks and in the `ordchr` gawk extension. Use a different name for the array for portability.

Comment: Ah thanks Ed. I didn't know about `ord` being a function.

Comment: Yeah, `ord()` returns the ordinal number of a character. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Ord.

Comment: hi Anubhava , is there a way to print comments in the output of all the file or at least first file ? I tried adding `/^#/{print;next}` but its messing the whole output

Comment: Sorry didn't understand this new requirement. Please edit the question and I will see if it is possible to tweak this solution

Answer (score 2):

A Perl solution would be to use an INI parser like [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny) to read each, merge the resulting data structure, and write out a new file. Note this does not preserve comments or ordering (for the latter, you could use [Config::Tiny::Ordered](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny::Ordered), but merging is harder).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Tiny;

my $config1 = Config::Tiny->read('f1');
my $config2 = Config::Tiny->read('f2');
foreach my $category (keys %$config2) {
  my $section1 = $config1->{$category} //= {};
  my $section2 = $config2->{$category};
  @$section1{keys %$section2} = values %$section2;
}
$config1->write('new');
```

Comment: thanks for help, although I do not have this module installed in the system. appreciate your help

Comment: Config::Tiny is pure-perl so could be [fatpacked](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) into a script.

Comment: You of course need to install App::FatPacker to do that, but the basic process would be: install App::cpanminus or download it from https://cpanmin.us; `cpanm -l local Config::Tiny`; `fatpack tree $(env PERL5LIB="$PWD/local/lib/perl5" fatpack packlists-for Config/Tiny.pm)`; `fatpack file script.pl > script.packed.pl`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n" }
{ key = $1 }
NR == FNR { rec[key] = $0; next }
key in rec { $1 = rec[key]; delete rec[key] }
{ print }
END {
    for (key in rec) {
        print rec[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
[default]
a1=1
b1=2
c1=3
a2=5
b2=6

[foo]
d=1
e1=5
c2=7
d2=8
e2=9

[bar]
f2=10
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU diff & sed):

```
diff -au999 file1 file2 | sed '1,3d;s/.//' >file3
```

Used `diff -u999` to unify file1 and fil2, then remove the 3 header lines and the first character from every line.

N.B. If file1 and file2 are the same you will get no output and the same keys will be repeated if they have different values.

Comment: this may only work in very simple cases; for exemple, it will fail if sections are not in the same order.